# how to call a javascript function if the href has the hash tag id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to call the javacsript function on href if the href has the hash tag id.I need the #table as i am using bootstrap tabs so cannot use javasript:show_create_msg();
here is my code

```
<a  href="#table:show_create_msg();">Table</a>
function show_create_msg()
{
   alert("error");
}
```

Comment: can you add some `id` or `class name` to the link and then bind a `click` event to the same?

Comment: Nowadays even `href="javascript:"` is misused. Use standard `onclick="function()"`. Or `addEventListener` directly in your code.

Comment: onclick is not working

Comment: Wait, what do you mean not working? :|

Comment: Update your question with your `onclick` implementation code, also are there any console error when you click it?

Comment: @Ninad When you want to call function? onload or onclick?

Answer (score 2):

> Add `onclick` event and `prevent`the click event, then its doesn't load the page when you click the link.

```
<a href="#table" onclick="show_create_msg();">Table</a>

<script>
function show_create_msg()
{
  alert('is working');
  // Do something;
  return false;
}
</script>
```

> incase you need to find hash `http://example.com#table`

```
<script>
function show_create_msg()
{
  alert('is working');
  // Do something;
  return false;
}
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash == '#table'){
  show_create_msg();
}
<script>
```

Comment: If you `return` you can't `// Do something`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `onclick` event to this link and then write a JavaScript function that does something:

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_create_msg();">Table</a>

<script>
function show_create_msg()
{
    // Do something;
}
</script>
```

Comment: i cannot use just # in href it has to be #table

Comment: If it because it moves to top of page, you'll have to use jQuery event like @codelock wrote. And `e.preventDefault();` is required to prevent from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your element an id, and attach a click event to it.

*I will show you how to do it in a more proper way (using "onclick" inline the element is not a good practice)*

Here's an example:

**HTML**

```
<a id="myLink" href="#table">Table</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#myLink').on('click',function(){
    show_create_msg();
});
```

or even better:

```
$('#myLink').on('click',function(){
    // your show_create_msg code here
});
```

If you want to prevent the default link behaviour:

```
$('#myLink').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // your show_create_msg code here
});
```

If you want to trigger the code only on specific hash value:

```
$('#myLink').on('click',function(e){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash=='#table'){
        // your show_create_msg code here
    }
});
```

If you don't want to use jQuery you can use native javascript code:

```
document.getElementById('myLink').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    // your show_create_msg code here
});
```

Hope it helps a bit

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your html source, get functoin name from `href` attribute of element and set it to `onclick` attribute of it.

```js
var fn = $("a").attr("href").replace("#table:", "");
$("a").attr("onclick", fn)

function show_create_msg(){
    console.log("function called");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#table:show_create_msg();">Table</a>
```